# Store array in cache using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I need to store an array in cache using Classic ASP. I am using the code below but it's not working.

```
var loans=[];
Application("loanArray")=loans;
```

Please let me know your thoughts as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike VBScript arrays -- which are similar to typical C-style arrays in that they are stored in contiguous, fixed-sized memory -- JScript arrays are sparse and dynamic. They're also apartment-threaded and, therefore, not  safe for use at ASP `Application` scope.

If you enable detailed error messages, you should see the following message appear if you try:

> Cannot add object with apartment model behavior to the application intrinsic object.

So you have a couple options here.

1. Store your array at `Session` scope. You can do this in your `global.asa`'s `Session_OnStart()` to make it available at the start of every session.

   ```
   var a = ['one', 2, 3.0, false];
   Session('myArray') = a;

   // or...

   Session('myArray') = ['one', 2, 3.0, false];
   ```
2. Store a thread-safe VBScript array at `Application` scope and convert it to a JScript array when you need access to it. For example:

   ```
   <script runat="server" language="vbscript">

       Application.Lock
       Application("myArray") = Array("one", 2, 3.0, False)
       Application.Unlock

   </script>

   <script runat="server" language="javascript">

       // Retrieve the array and convert it to a JavaScript array...
       var a = VBArray(Application("myArray")).toArray();

       for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
           Response.Write(a[i] + '<br>');
       }

   </script>
   ```